# Calculating Flux Across a Simple Closed Curve lying on an (x,z)-cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

[image]

I am having some difficulties with the problem above. The approach I'm using is the following:

Use Stokes Theorem to instead show that $$\iint_{S} \text{curl $(\vec{G})$} \cdot \hat{n} \text{ }ds =0,$$
where $S$ is the region enclosed by $C$. I've computed curl $(\vec{G})=z \hat{j}$. From here I'm not sure where to go as I don't see how to compute $\hat n$ in this case.

Comment: Note that you should type your question as opposed to including an image of it. Using an image makes your question unsearchable which means people in the future with the same question will be unable to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true. Take the "$(x,z)$" cylinder $x^2+(z-1)^2=1$ for instance. Computing the surface integral of the curl over a slice of constant $y$ gives us

$$\iint\limits_{x^2+(z-1)^2=1}z\hat{j}\cdot \hat{j}dS = \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\sin\theta}r^2\sin\theta\:dr\:d\theta = \frac{8}{3} \int_0^\pi \sin^4\theta \:d\theta \neq 0$$

Comment: Hmm, I think perhaps it is true if we have the extra condition that $C$ does not wrap around the $(x,y)$-cylinder. If we just draw a simple closed curve that does not wrap around the given surface, then the normal vector, $\hat n$, would have no $\hat j$-component. Thus, the dot product in the integrand would be 0. Does that make sense or does is the statement still false under this extra restriction of $C$?

Comment: @FrenchToastCrunch it really depends where the problem came from.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: If the cylinder contains lines parallel to the $y$-axis, what do you know about $\vec n$? I believe the hypothesis should be that the curve bounds a region *in* the cylinder.

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is poorly phrased, but believe that by "lying on an $(x,z)$- cylinder" they meant that the curve is on the cylinder in such a way that it can be shrunken down to a point (in other words, the curve can't be drawn in such a way that it wraps around the cylinder). Under this new interpretation, $\vec{n}$ has no $\hat j$ component and thus the dot product above is $0$. That's what I'm thinking.